# Practical Alternative for Windows Scheduled Tasks (small shop)

Tags: windows, scheduling

I work in a very small shop (2 people), and since I started a few months back we have been relying on Windows Scheduled tasks.  Finally, I've decided I've had enough grief with some of its inabilities such as

1. No logs that I can find except on a domain level (inaccessible to machine admins who aren't domain admins)
2. No alerting mechanism (e-mail, for one) when the job fails.

Once again, we are a small shop.  I'm looking to do the analogous scheduling system upgrade than I'm doing with source control (VSS --> Subversion).  I'm looking for suggestions of systems that

1. Are able to do the two things outlined above
2. Have been community-tested.  I'd love to be a guinae pig for exciting software, but job scheduling is not my day job.
3. Ability to remotely manage jobs a plus
4. Free a plus.  Cheap is okay, but I have very little interest in going through a full blown sales pitch with 7 power point presentations.
5. Built-in ability to run common tasks besides .EXE's a (minor) plus (run an assembly by name, run an Excel macro by name a plus, run a database stored procedure, etc.).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you can look at :

http://www.visualcron.com/

Comment: this looks very promising.  i'll take a look.

Comment: Super easy install, a little tinkering (~20 minutes) to setup a couple of specialized jobs, great UI for managing jobs.  I know windows scheduled tasks is a low bar to surpass, but this is head and sholders better than most sub 1,000 dollar products.

Comment: I've been very satisfied with this product.  It is totally worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider Cygwin and its version of "cron".  It meets requirements #1 thru 4 (though without a nice UI for #3.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a free tool there is plenty of implementations for the popular Cron tool for Windows, for example [CRONw](http://cronw.sourceforge.net/). It's pretty easy to configure and maintain. You could easily write add custom WSH scripts to send your emails and add log entries.

If you're going commercial way BMC Control-M is arguably one of the best but I don't believe that it is particularly cheap.

You may also consider some upcoming packages like [JobScheduler](http://jobscheduler.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Apologize for kicking up the dust here on a very old thread. But I couldn't disagree more with what's been presented here.

Scheduled tasks in Windows are AWESOME (a %^#% load better than writing services I might add). Yes, not without limitations. But still extremely powerful. I rely on them in earnest for a variety of different things.

If you even have a *slight* grasp on c# you can write as custom "task" (essentially a console application) to do, well, virtually anything. If persistent/accessible logging is what you're after, why not something like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)? Even at the time of writing, it had a very robust feature set. This tool in and of itself, in conjunction with some c#, could've solved both your problems very easily.

Perhaps I'm missing the point, but it seems to me that this isn't really a problem. At least not anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question, but we use [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/).  Yes its main purpose is for CI\CD, but its also a really nice UI for CRON with a ton of plugins and integrations.